# How to differentiate between two types of images using image processing?

Tags: python, image-processing, deep-learning, canny-operator

I have two categories of images segmented using MaskRCNN. First category contains dent images on car.

Second category contains images of reflection/shadows fallen on car that the Mask RCNN detects as dent.

Is there any methods in image processing that can distinguish between the same? I tried Canny, Gaussian, LBP, SIFT, watershed etc. Can anyone suggest a suitable approach for the same.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

If the image of shadows generally are darker than the dents, you can convert the images to HSV, and compare the average V values of the pixels. V value contains the brightness of the pixel.

You can use `hsv_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.BGR2HSV)`.

Comment: i converted the RGB image to HSV and split values of HSV and find average of V using  **np.average(v)** is this what you mean? And i am getting same range of values for dents and reflections. Is there any other possible way?

Comment: If you average all the V values for every pixels in a single image, you will get a single integer(I don't understand what you mean by range). You can compare that integer between two images. If dent images are generally brighter than reflections, the dent images should generally have a bigger integer. You could set a certain limit, if the integer is below the limit, it's reflections, if it's higher, it's dents. You can set the limit by just "trial and error" or if you know the labels, you could use another classification model.

Comment: For this to work, you should confirm that the dent images are in fact brighter than the reflection images. If that's not the case, you can use other values, such as color values. If one has certain color attributes to it.